# PowerShell script runs with error first time, but correctly second or third time

Tags: powershell

I have a script to disable users in AD with the following steps:

- asks for username
- set "domain users" group as primary group
- disable users in AD
- move to disabled OU
- clear Manager from AD
- remove all groups except 'domain users'
- Add disabled_mailboxes to the user
- Hide account from exchande list

Now, when i try the first time it does not work. i have to run it several times like 2 3 and 4 times to work.

When i run it step by step, it work fine also from the first time

and here is the script:

```
$username = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter Username'
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.E2010
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$user = Get-ADUser -Filter {(SamAccountName -eq $username)} -Properties MemberOf

#set "domain users" group as primary group
$group = get-adgroup "Domain Users" -properties @("primaryGroupToken")
get-aduser $username | set-aduser -replace @{primaryGroupID=$group.primaryGroupToken}

#disable users in AD
Get-ADUser -Filter {(SamAccountName -eq $username)} | Disable-ADAccount -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

#move to disabled OU
Get-ADUser -Filter {(SamAccountName -eq $username)} | Move-ADObject –TargetPath “OU=Users,OU=Disabled Objects,DC=xxxxxxx,DC=xxx,DC=XXX”

#clear Manager from AD
Get-ADUser -Filter {(SamAccountName -eq $username)} | Set-ADUser -Clear manager

#-------------------------



#remove all groups except 'domain users'
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $username | % {Remove-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $username -MemberOf $_ -Confirm:$false -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue}

#code can be removed.
#$group = $user | Select-Object -ExpandProperty MemberOf
#Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity $group -Members $user.SamAccountName -Confirm:$false -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

#-------------------------


#Add disabled_mailboxes to the user
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity 'disabled_mailboxes' -Member $User.SamAccountName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
#-------------------------


#Hide account from exchande list
Set-Mailbox -identity $user.SamAccountName -HiddenFromAddressListsEnabled $true -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

Windows 2012R2, Exchange 2010

Can anyone help with that???

Thanks

Mina

Comment: Seen something similar, i think it might be replication issue, wil look at it later, could you add the errors to the question? make sure the ErrorAction is set to "Continue" and not "SilentlyContinue" this suppresses the errors

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `Get-ADUser` repeatedly in the sequential lines. Just use the existing `$user` variable that you've just populated with values. Most likely you are hitting an issue that `Get-ADUser` returns old cached value for DN right after you run `Move-ADObject` (this changes the DN of the user), and since all queries use DN to locate the user, you get the error. The second run has the target user already in the destination OU, so no errors arise.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tested that with one user now, and it looks promising. I will continue testing more.